# i am trying to change my html site to php but it shows error?

Tags: php, html

i want to convert my **.html** page to **.PHP** but when I change the extension it shows error 404 not found.

how can it be properly converted to a PHP page?

Comment: Are you referencing the .html page or the .php page (i.e. index.php)? Also, are you running your site on a web server (if not then you will receive more errors).

Comment: Remember that linux/unix systems are case sensitive, use `.php` not `.PHP`

Answer (score 0):

- HTML is rendered on the client (your browser).
- PHP is run on a server.

You'll need a server to host your php scripts. A server like the apache web server for example.

Or you could use the php development server to get started quickly.

- Open a terminal in the folder that has your php code.
- type `php -S localhost:8000` into your terminal
- In your browser go to http://localhost:8000

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SwWo0wHx6Q) I found that can help you learn more about the difference between client side and server side.

Comment: No i am using Linux server(cpanel)  but still it shows error!

Comment: well you're gonna have to elaborate more on the environment and the directory structure so that we can help.